# Extracting specific columns from multiple CSVs into new CSV

Tags: powershell

I want to extract columns by header name from multiple CSVs into one 'master file'. I have tried multiple things but each time there is something else that occurs.
I have this code which is working now, but extremely tedious typing out which header name I need for every column, as there will be upwards of 20 of columns I need from each CSV.
Anyone have any suggestions? I'm currently using PS, but am open to other methods.

```
Import-Csv -Path $inputFilePath1 | ForEach-Object {

$File1Values.Add($_.HBA_ID, $_)

}
 

Import-Csv -Path $inputFilePath2 | Select-Object *, 
| Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation

@{ N = "TOPF_IQ_Zscore"; E = { $File1Values[$_.HBA_ID].TOPF_IQ_Zscore } },
@{ N = "TMT_A_Zscore"; E = { $File1Values[$_.HBA_ID].TOPF_IQ_Zscore } },
@{ N = "TOPF_IQ_Zscore"; E = { $File1Values[$_.HBA_ID].TOPF_IQ_Zscore } },
@{ N = "TOPF_IQ_Zscore"; E = { $File1Values[$_.HBA_ID].TOPF_IQ_Zscore } },
@{ N = "TOPF_IQ_Zscore"; E = { $File1Values[$_.HBA_ID].TOPF_IQ_Zscore } },
@{ N = "TOPF_IQ_Zscore"; E = { $File1Values[$_.HBA_ID].TOPF_IQ_Zscore } },
@{ N = "TOPF_IQ_Zscore"; E = { $File1Values[$_.HBA_ID].TOPF_IQ_Zscore } },
@{ N = "TOPF_IQ_Zscore"; E = { $File1Values[$_.HBA_ID].TOPF_IQ_Zscore } },
@{ N = "TOPF_IQ_Zscore"; E = { $File1Values[$_.HBA_ID].TOPF_IQ_Zscore } } |
 Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do all CSVs have the same header names? Your code seem to be mostly a copy paste of `@{ N = "TOPF_IQ_Zscore"; E = { $File1Values[$_.HBA_ID].TOPF_IQ_Zscore } },` and in all honesty, it doesn't seem to have much sense.

Comment: No, they don't. I did that as an example.

Comment: What dictates what column you pull from the csv?

Comment: The header name

Comment: you can try to use Join-Object 
 (https://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/) stating which columns you want to join from both tables.